# Fetchtype EAGER not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have read and made sure my annotations are right. I am using spring data jpa and fetching a parent class with child relation annotated with fetch type as EAGER but JPA is not pulling child objects.

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "Customer_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int customerid;
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Car> cars;
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int carId;
    private String make;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerid")
    private Customer customers;
```

Customer repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>{

    Set<Customer> findByName(String name);
```

repository to fetch customer data:

```
public Data getCustomer(int id) {
        Data data = new Data();

        try {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(id);
```

This repository method is only fetching customer though I have annotated it to fetch eager to pull child objects.

Comment: Have you tried to use @JoinColumn(name = "Customer_ID")? I think your relationship is broken

Comment: @robert08 I just tried it but it didn't help. Do you see any other thing broken that affect EAGER fetch.

Comment: I found the problem. It was the problem with how I save the customer. I am not setting the customer entity to Car when I save it, so customer_id is always null. I thought jpa/hi9bernate will take care of it with @JoinColumn annotation but looks like I have to manually set it.